# why CANT The screen display data table?KivyMD

Tags: python, mysql, kivy, mysql-connector, kivymd

```
import mysql.connector as sql
details = {}
connect = sql.connect(host= 'localhost' ,user = 'root',password = "****" ,database='courier_service_system' )
sqlcursor = connect.cursor()
sqlcursor.execute("select * from billings")
billings_detail = sqlcursor.fetchall()
for x in range(1,len(billings_detail)+1):
    billings_detail[x-1] = (x,)+billings_detail[x-1]
sqlcursor.execute("select * from login")
for x in sqlcursor.fetchall():
    x = list(x)
    username, password = x[1], x[2]
    details[username] = password
connect.commit()
sqlcursor.close()
connect.close()

class Login_page(Screen):
    pass
class Billings_Table(Screen):
    def load_table(self):
        layout = AnchorLayout()
        self.sm.data_tables = MDDataTable(
            use_pagination=True,
            check=True,
            rows_num=8,
            column_data=[
                (" Sr.no ", dp(50)),
                (" Weight ", dp(50)),
                (" Price(in rupees) ", dp(50)),
                ],
            row_data=billings_detail,
            elevation=2,
        )
        self.add_widget(self.data_tables)
        return layout

    def on_enter(self):
        self.load_table()


class Sign_in_Page(Screen):
    pass
class Main_page(Screen):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
        self.sm.add_widget(Login_page(name = "Login_Page"))
        self.sm.add_widget(Sign_in_Page(name="Sign_in_Page"))
        self.sm.add_widget(Main_page(name = "Main_page"))
        self.sm.add_widget(Billings_Table(name="Billings_Table"))



        return self.sm

    username = ObjectProperty()
    password = ObjectProperty()

    def validate_user(self):
        if self.username.text in details.keys():
            self.sm.current = "Main_page"
            self.username.text = ""
            self.password.text = ""
        else:
            print("Not here!")

    def change_screen(self, tela):
        self.sm.current = tela

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

this is the .kv file :

```
<Login_Page>:
    MDScreen:
        MDToolbar:
            title : "Courier Service System"
            pos_hint : {"top":1}
        Image :
            source : "courier_design(256256).png"
            pos_hint : {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.7}
        MDTextField :
            id : "Username"
            hint_text: "Enter Username"
            halign : "center"
            size_hint : (0.25, 0.10)
            pos_hint : {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.45}
            font_size : 12
        MDTextField :
            hint_text : "Password"
            halign : "center"
            size_hint : (0.25, 0.1)
            pos_hint : {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.35}
            font_size : 12
            password : True
        MDFillRoundFlatButton :
            text : "Log in"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25,0.05)
            pos_hint : {'center_x' : 0.5,'center_y' : 0.28}
            on_release: app.root.current = "Main_page"
        MDLabel :
            text : "——————— or ———————"
            font_size : 15
            size_hint : (0.25, 0.05)
            pos_hint : {'center_x': 0.508, 'center_y': 0.23}
            theme_text_color : "Secondary"
        MDFillRoundFlatButton :
            text : "Sign in"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.25, 0.05)
            pos_hint : {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.18}
            on_release: app.root.current = "Sign_in_Page"
<Sign_in_Page>:
    MDScreen:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDToolbar:
            title: "To Login Page"
            left_action_items: [["arrow-left",  lambda x: app.change_screen("Login_Page")]]
            pos_hint : {"top":1}
        MDTextField :
            id : "Username"
            hint_text: "Enter New Username"
            align : "center"
            size_hint : (0.4, 0.1)
            pos_hint : {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.6}
            font_size : 20
        MDTextField :
            hint_text: "Enter New Password"
            align : "center"
            size_hint : (0.4, 0.1)
            pos_hint : {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
            font_size : 12
            password : True
        #convert button
        MDFillRoundFlatButton :
            text : "Create Acoount"
            font_size : 12
            size_hint : (0.4, 0.07)
            pos_hint : {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.25}
            on_release: app.root.current = "Login_Page"
<Main_page>
    MDScreen:
        MDLabel :
            text : "Our Services :"
            align : "center"
            font_size : 30
            size_hint : (0.5, 0.5)
            pos_hint : {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.8}
            theme_text_color : "Secondary"
        MDToolbar:
            title: "Back"
            left_action_items: [["arrow-left",  lambda x: app.change_screen("Login_Page")]]
            pos_hint : {"top":1}
            font_size : 15

        MDFillRoundFlatButton :
            text : "Courier Order and Customer Details"
            font_size : 14
            size_hint : (0.4, 0.09)
            pos_hint : {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.6}
        MDFillRoundFlatButton :
            text : "Billings Details"
            font_size : 14
            size_hint : (0.4, 0.09)
            pos_hint : {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.4}
            on_release: app.root.current ='Billings_Table'
        MDFillRoundFlatButton :
            text : "Our Employees"
            font_size : 14
            size_hint : (0.4, 0.09)
            pos_hint : {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.2}
<Billings_Table>

    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: "Back"
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.06
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.8}
        on_release : app.root.current = 'Main_page'
    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        text: "Load Table"
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.06
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        on_release :  root.load_table()
```

basically i'm trying to import a table from mysql and then display its data  but after trying some solution online this is the error i'm getting
self.sm.data_tables = MDDataTable(
AttributeError: 'Billings_Table' object has no attribute 'sm'
can anyone say how should i solve this i don't know how to export the screen outside from mainapp and also any suggestions on the main code will be appreciated

Comment: Please take a note that you created the `MDDataTable` as `self.sm.data_tables` but add it to the screen as `self.data_tables`. I hope you got that.

Comment: it gives an error if try .sm